# What's the defining equation of a retarded Green's function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, classical-field-theory

The retarded Green's function $G_R(x,x^\prime)$ is usually defined by using the Wightman function $$W(x,x^\prime) = \langle0| \varphi(x) \varphi(x^\prime) |0\rangle\,,$$ [by](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/20812/37286)
$$ G_R(x,x^\prime) = \Theta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0}) W(x,x^\prime).$$ 
The defining condition of a Green's function, however, is that it fulfills
$$ D_x G(x, x^\prime) = \delta(x - x^\prime)\,, $$ 
where $D_x$ is a differential operator. Moreover, the corresponding Wightman function fulfills 
$$ D_x W(x, x^\prime) = 0 \,, $$ 
What's the defining equation of a retarded Green's function? By using the equations given above, we can calculate
\begin{align}
D_x G_R(x, x^\prime)&= D_x\Theta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0}) W(x,x^\prime) \\
&= \Big( D_x\Theta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0})\Big) W(x,x^\prime) +  \Theta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0}) \Big( D_xW(x,x^\prime)\Big)\\
&= \delta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0}) W(x,x^\prime) .
\end{align}
In a more general context, we replace the Wightman function by the kernel $K(x,x^\prime)$ of the corresponding equation:
$$ D_x G_R(x, x^\prime)=\delta(x^0 - x^{\prime\,0}) K(x,x^\prime).$$ 
Is this the correct defining equation of a retarded Green's function? And if yes, how can we understand it?

Comment: I should expect that the equal time kernel should yield $\delta^{d-1}(x-x')$.

Comment: Ah yes. In the equal time limit the Kernel becomes the delta distribution. In addition, i believe the correct equation is given here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123587/analytical-problems-with-greens-function